# How can I change the size of background of DateCalendar's selected date in MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the size of background of DateCalendar's selected date in MUI(material-UI). I tried to change it with chainging some css using `styled(DateCalendar)` as the below. However, When I click the dates, it interrupted calendar as following :

[image]

How can I resolve this?

**My code**

```
 const CustomDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)`
    .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root {
    display: none;
    }
    .MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin {
        margin-top: -15px;
    },
    .MuiPickersDay-dayOutsideMonth{
        margin: 30px;
    }
    .css-i5q14k-MuiDayCalendar-header{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected {
        background-color: #209214 !important;
        }
        
    .MuiPickersDay-root:hover {
        background-color: transparent;       
        }
    
      .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
      }
   
        `;

    const customTheme = createTheme({
        typography: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
            fontSize : 11,
            fontWeightBold : 1,
        },
        
        components: {
            MuiButton: { 
              styleOverrides: { 
                root: { minWidth: "10px",
                borderRadius: '10px' } 
              } 
            }
          },
          
    });
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
    const handleDateChange = (date:any) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
      };

    return (
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="row" justifyContent="space-between">
    <Box>
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} locale="ko">
            <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
                <CustomDateCalendar  
                    defaultCalendarMonth={dayjs('2023-06-01')}
                    disablePast = {false}
                    views={['day']}
                    disableFuture = {false}
                    maxDate = {dayjs('2023-06-30')}
                    minDate = {dayjs('2023-06-12')}
                    sx={{
                        ...{
                            '& .MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected': {
                                width: 20,
                                height: 20,
                            }
                        },
                        marginTop: "85px",
                        marginLeft: "1px",
                        height: "180px",
                        width: "326px",
                        border: "1px solid #EFEFEF",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                    }}
                    value={selectedDate}
                    onChange={handleDateChange}    
                    />
            </ThemeProvider>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    </Box> 
    );
  };
```

Comment: Probably doesn't make much sense to try and change the dimensions of the selected day's element only, you can pretty much expect it to fall apart then. The elements should all have the same width and height. If you can't make them all bigger, then keep the selected one at the same size, and use a positioned pseudo element to apply the background, that you can easily make "bigger" than the element that actually contains it.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Mui-selected rule in your code. Something like this:

```
.MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #209214 !important;
}
```

Here you can adjust the size and shape as per your requirements.

And i would probably use an adjustment between the dates

```
.MuiPickersCalendar-transitionContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -4px;
}
```